# Difference in major product of sulphonation of phenols

Tags: organic-chemistry

When phenol is sulphonated by fuming sulfuric acid at a lower temperature, the *ortho* product is the major whereas at higher temperature the *para* product is formed as the major.

Why does this happen, because looking at the reaction mechanism, it appears to me that *para* should always be the major.

Is it the kinetic control vs thermodynamic control effect?? If yes, then why is *para* thermodynamically more stable and *ortho* kinetically faster??

Comment: Check [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/124274/50406)

Comment: It's because at lower temperature H-bonding exert extra stability to ortho product while at higher temperature H bond get break so stability of o-product become less than para product