# Reaction of phenol with concentrated sulfuric acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

What is the product when phenol reacts with conc. $\ce{H2SO4}$ in excess?

I have been told that the major product will be *ortho* at low temperature and *para* at high temperature. Why cannot it form both *ortho-* and *para*-substituted product as in the case of picric acid?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/117608/difference-in-major-product-of-sulphonation-of-phenols

Comment: Also: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/44090/preparation-of-picric-acid

Answer (score 4):

It's a reversible reaction, so at higher temperature the thermodynamic para product is formed from the kinetic ortho product.

Further reading [here](https://www.cliffsnotes.com/study-guides/chemistry/organic-chemistry-ii/phenols-and-aryl-halides/reactions-of-phenolic-benzene-rings).

Comment: Why does it only form a monosulphonated product and why not a trisulphonated product

Comment: Because the mono-product is strongly electron-withdrawn and the electrophile is not as good as NO2+

Comment: And because the forcing conditions needed to further sulfonate cause a range of other oxidative reactions leading to a complex mixture.

Comment: Why is the ortho product the kinetically controlled product? I would've assumed that the attack at the para position is faster since the ortho position suffers the negative inductive effect of the oxygen.